# Next.js App: Retrieving Chat History Using Prisma and Axios, Stuck at 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, axios, prisma

So, my goal is to retrieve chat history. If there is an ID in the URL when the page is loaded, that means there was already a chat set (if the ID corresponds*). I attempt to retrieve the data from the database using Prisma.

I'm working with nextJs/app router so to do that I made a folder [slug] to have dynamic routes

I get the slug like that

```js
export default function ConversationPage({
  params,
}: {
  params: { slug: string };
}) {
  console.log("my slug:", params.slug);
```

So if there is a slug I try to get the data, **that's where I'm stuck currently**

What I've tried so far:

On my page I use a useEffect:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/conversation/get", {
        id: params.slug,
      });
      console.log("Conversation data:", response);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [params.slug]);
```

I builded a function in my api

```js
export async function POST(req: any) {
  const { userId } = auth();

  if (!userId) {
    return new NextResponse("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
  }

  const { id } = req.params;
  const chatContent = await getConversationHistory(id);

  return NextResponse.json(chatContent);
}
```

And that api call this function:

```js
export const getConversationHistory = async (chatId: any) => {
  const { userId } = auth();

  if (!userId) {
    return false;
  }

  try {
    const conversationHistory = await prismadb.conversationHistory.findUnique({
      where: {
        userId: userId,
        id: chatId,
      },
    });

    if (!conversationHistory) {
      return false;
    }

    return conversationHistory.content;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching conversation history:", error);
    throw error;
  } finally {
    await prismadb.$disconnect();
  }
};
```

my prisma schema:

```js
model ConversationHistory {
  id String @id @default(cuid())
  userId String 
  label String
  content Json
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

The error:

> Object { stack:
> "AxiosError@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:24:19\nsettle@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:24:12\nonloadend@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:125:66\nEventHandlerNonNull*dispatchXhrRequest@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:139:7\n__webpack_exports__.default<@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:63:10\ndispatchRequest@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:61:10\nrequest@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:155:77\nhttpMethod@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:194:19\nwrap@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/bind.js:9:15\nfetchData@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./app/(dashboard)/(rout…",
> message: "Request failed with status code 500", name: "AxiosError",
> code: "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest,
> response: {…} }

Comment: give me a full log of axios

Comment: - error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'req.params' as it is undefined.

Comment: **const { id } = req.params;** log the params, should be missing data from the url.